# Distributions of hitting times of Brownian motion are continuous with respect to Lebesgue Measure

Tags: probability-theory

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion on $\mathbb R^n$, started at 0. Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a closed set at positive distance from 0 and $\tau_A = \inf\{t > 0 :B_t \in A\}$. Under what conditions on $A$ is the distribution of $\tau_A$ absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?

I know that in the one-dimensional case, $\tau_A$ is the same as the exit time from $[a,b]$ for some (possibly half-infinite) interval, and we can find an explicit formula for a density for $\tau_A$, so the result holds for any choice of $A$ in dimension 1. But, I am not sure about higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No condition except that $A$ is at positive distance.

Choose $r$ small enough such that the closed ball centered at zero with radius $r$ does not meet $A$. Then $\tau_A=\tau_r+\sigma_A$ where $\tau_r$ denotes the first hitting time of the sphere centered at zero with radius $r$ and $\sigma_A=\tau_A-\tau_r$. Note that $\sigma_A$ is the first hitting time of $A$ by a Brownian motion starting at a point uniformly distributed on the sphere. And $\sigma_A$ and $\tau_r$ are independent because the first hitting point of the sphere is independent of the first hitting time $\tau_r$.

To conclude, use the specific fact that the distribution of $\tau_r$ is absolutely continuous and the general fact that, for every independent random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ such that the distribution of $\xi$ is absolutely continuous, the distribution of $\xi+\eta$ is absolutely continuous

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one point is unclear. How do we know that the distribution of $\tau_r$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Because we know the density of its distribution... Say, which textbook are you using?

Comment: I have Peres and Morters, and Revuz and Yor.